# Spring boot enable/disable embedded tomcat with profile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm writing a Spring Boot application that uses one of several `@Configuration` classes depending on which `@Profile` is set in the `application.properties`file.

One of those Configuration classes uses a REST interface, and therefore I'm including `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency.

This starts up an embedded Tomcat instance, which is fine.

The problem is, the other profiles don't need an embedded server (e.g. I'm using JMS to handle incoming messages instead of REST).

Is there any way to stop the `@SpringBootApplication` from starting up Tomcat by default, and only using it for the REST Configuration class?
E.g., by annotating that class with `@EnableWebMVC`

Here's an example of my `@Configuration`classes:

REST:

```
@Profile({"REST"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class HttpConfiguration{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

JMS:

```
@Profile({"JMS"})
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfiguration{
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.class})`  for the JMS profile. This should exclude auto configuration of Embedded Servlet container

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                                  WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

to exclude Spring Boot's auto-configuration for embedded servlet containers. Additionally, you need to set the following property for the non-REST cases, so that Spring Boot won't try to start a `WebApplicationContext` (which needs a servlet container):

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

Then enable the embedded Tomcat in your REST profile by importing `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class` (this delays the autoconfiguration until after the REST profile has been loaded:

```
@Profile({"REST"})
@Configuration
@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
public class HttpConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

If you are using any `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`s, you also need to import `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessorRegistrar.class`.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely looks like the right track. Seeing this exception now: Exception in thread "main"     `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh`

Comment: One other issue I had was that when using `@Import(EmbeddedTomcat.class)` the server.port property was ignored, and I was stuck on port 8080. I managed to overcome that by swapping the import to `@Import(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)` at that point, so it didn't attempt the autoconfiguration until after the relevant `@Configuration` class was loaded.

Comment: Fore reference I preferred to use this annotation to exclude auto configurations : `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { ... })`

Comment: spring.main.web-environment , deprecated in springBoot 2.1.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 34):

As of Spring Boot 2.0 only `spring.main.web-application-type=none` in the relevant profile do the trick.

If you use a multi-document `application.yml` with Spring Boot 2.0, adding this block and replacing `no-web-profile-name` with the profile that shouldn't have an embedded web server should work:

```
---
spring:
  profiles: no-web-profile-name
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

Answer (score 21):

The answers from @hzpz and @orid set me on the right track.

I needed to add

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

and set:

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

in my `application.properties` file for the non-Rest cases.

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for the credit! However, your answer would have been better as an edit to my answer, since my answer was obviously missing some crucial parts. I did the edit myself to make it a proper answer to your problem.

Comment: @hzpz Sorry, didn't realise I could edit someone else's comment. Thanks for the help.