# about spring boot how to disable web environment correctly

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot non-web application, when start it has below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Then I tried below manner

```
new SpringApplication().setWebEnvironment(false);
```

then start it still have above error.

Then tried

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but still have the same error.

At last I tried add below configuration in `application.properties`

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

this time it works.

Why the first two manner cannot work?

Comment: Post the actual code not a snippet... There are more lines in your `main` method. So post the application class.

Comment: Try this `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                                  WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})`
as 
[Suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078015/spring-boot-enable-disable-embedded-tomcat-with-profile)

Comment: @SanjayRawat still not work, please see https://github.com/zhugw/spring-boot-disable-web-environment

Comment: @M.Deinum please see https://github.com/zhugw/spring-boot-disable-web-environment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This answer is obsolete. Please note the other answer for Spring Boot 2.0**

*Original answer for Spring Boot 1.x:*

The reason this config is not working because these are two different instances:

```
new SpringApplication().setWebEnvironment(false); 
SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.class, args);
```

You are disabling `setWebEnvironment(false)` in `new SpringApplication()` object and calling static method `run()` on `SpringApplication.run(...)` which is different one.

I figured out 3 ways to do this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication implements CommandLineRunner{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//      Method#1: Using SpringApplicationBuilder.

        SpringApplication springApplication = 
                new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .sources(SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.class)
                .web(false)
                .build();

        springApplication.run(args);

//--------------------------------------------------------      

//      Method#2: Using SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.     

//      SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication springBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication = 
//              new SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication();
//      springBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.run(args);

//--------------------------------------------------------      

//      Method#3: Using SpringApplication().

//      SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
//      springApplication.setWebEnvironment(false);
//      
//      Set<Object> sources = new HashSet<>();
//      sources.add(SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.class);
//      springApplication.setSources(sources);
//      springApplication.run(args);

//--------------------------------------------------------  

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, Spring Boot gives many options ;)");
    }
}
```

Here is the complete working [Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/spring-boot-disable-web-environment).

And you don't need to exclude below config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class, 
                              WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Because you don't have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay Rawat but if only could disable web environment by `setWebEnviroment(false)`, cannot through excluding some key class to achieve this

Comment: @zhuguowei See Method #3.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Please note the other answer for Spring Boot 2.0

Answer (score 62):

### Starting from Spring Boot 2.0

-web(false)/setWebEnvironment(false) is deprecated and instead Web-Application-Type can be used to specify

- [Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

  ```
  spring.main.web-application-type=NONE 
  # REACTIVE, SERVLET
  ```
- or [SpringApplicationBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#web-org.springframework.boot.WebApplicationType-)

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootDisableWebEnvironmentApplication.class)
              .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) // .REACTIVE, .SERVLET
              .run(args);
     }
  }
  ```

---

Where [WebApplicationType](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/boot/WebApplicationType.html):

> - `NONE` - The application should not run as a web application and should not start an embedded web server.
> - `REACTIVE` - The application should run as a reactive web application and should start an embedded reactive web server.
> - `SERVLET` - The application should run as a servlet-based web application and should start an embedded servlet web server.

Courtesy: [Another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394305/4604542)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a Spring Boot 2 solution; I was looking for a migration from Spring 1.

Comment: In your example, it's not clear where I would put code to handle the arguments passed to the `run()` method. It's also not clear where I put my application code.

Answer (score 4):

As already noted in other answers the simplest solution is to add a property:

- `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` for Spring-boot 2.x
- `spring.main.web-environment=false` for Spring-boot 1.x

But the simplest solution is **NOT the best one**, it's just quick&dirty.
Spring-boot has a lot of autoconfigurations that are triggered by the content of your classpath, so you probably have some unnecessary web-related dependency in your app.

I had a Spring-batch application that was giving

```
Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

It was caused by the presence of `javax.servlet-api` in my POM.  I removed it and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication(Application.class)
       .setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE)
       .run(args);
}
```

is another way instead of using the `SpringApplicationBuilder`.