# Don't spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux work together?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

When I start to learn the `spring-webflux`, I have the question about this component.

I built a simple project, using maven to manage it. I addded the dependencies related to `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, like :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But it doesn't work. When removing the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, it can work well.

Comment: they are mutually exclusive, you either use webflux (reactive API) or web (Servlet API)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As explained in [the Spring Boot reference documentation section about the web environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.web-environment), adding both web and webflux starters will configure a Spring MVC web application.

This is behaving like that, because many existing Spring Boot web applications (using MVC) will depend on the webflux starter to use the `WebClient`. [Spring MVC partially support reactive return types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types), so this is an expected use case. The opposite isn't really true, since a reactive application is not really likely to use Spring MVC bits.

So using both web and webflux starters is supported, but it will configure a Spring MVC application. You can always force the Spring Boot application to be reactive with:

```java
SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)
```

But it's still a good idea to clean up dependencies as it would be easy to use a blocking feature in your reactive web application.

Comment: There is also property that allows achieve the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234523/5562284

`spring.main.web-application-type=reactive`

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue using `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and `spring-data-geode` causing

```
DEBUG [http-nio-8082-exec-2] org.sprin.web.servl.resou.ResourceHttpRequestHandler 454 handleRequest: Resource not found
```

It was resolved by changing the application type

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Web {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Web.class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
        SpringApplication.run(Web.class, args);
    }
}
```

The whole class used to look like this

[image]

After setting the application type, if I don't then call the `SpringApplication` in a static way, I get this:

[image: Web]

So it's changed to `app.run(args)`

Comment: are you sure you resolved something? because the `app` variable you declared actually is useless, as you run the Spring Boot app the traditional way (last line)...

Comment: it looks like you're right it looks like it should be `app.run` but maybe because the `SpringApplication.run` takes the class `Web.class` which is the name of the class where the `app` is defined, it uses that instead of a default. I edited the code above.

Comment: that doesn't change anything; setting the `webApplicationType` to a variable that is not used by `SpringApplication.run()` is useless. `SpringApplication.run()` is a static method, so once Java runs it, the `app` variable is lost...

Comment: I updated the question again with what I saw and, yeah... oui... except the spring `run` does at least refer to the `Web.class` are you sure?

Comment: `SpringApplication.run(Web.class, args);` where `Web.class` is the name of the class that declares a `SpringApplication app` of type `REACTIVE` and it works... `so don't fix it`?!

Comment: because you have to write: `app.run(args);` not use the `Web.class` anymore!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220965/discussion-between-rupweb-and-maxxyme).

Comment: @maxxyme you were right all along, so I changed the code above to `app.run(args)`