# Spring Boot - NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter && Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext when trying to use Netty

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use Netty server. So I excluded Tomcat in the pom.ml file;

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run the application, I'm getting the error **Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter**

Then I add the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then again when I run the application, I'm getting the error
**org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.**

I've checked several questions and no luck yet.

Any ideas?

### Enviroment

- Boot:    2.1.3.RELEASE
- Eclipse: 4.7

Comment: I tried with your pom.xml without adding the servlet dependency it started fine

Comment: Do you want to build a reactive reactive web api or a classic servlet-based api? This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377675/does-not-the-spring-boot-starter-web-and-spring-boot-starter-webflux-work-togeth

Comment: @Santoshb, I executed the app in another computer and ran without issues. I guess something was corrupt in my local. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve yes, my idea was to build an app to execute both, but i see now that is not the correct approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the netty server in WebFlux and WebFlux (spring-boot-starter-webflux) use by default netty server and spring-boot-starter-web use by default tomcat server.

WebFlux provides a choice of servers (Netty, Tomcat, Jetty, Undertow, and Servlet 3.1+ containers). Both Tomcat and Jetty are servlet based servers but Netty and Undertow are non-servlet based servers.

If you want to use netty server and external jar in which using servlet API then you have to add the below dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```