# Spring Boot livenessState: DOWN and readinessState: OUT_OF_SERVICE even if application is running fine

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, http-status-code-503, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

i'm developing/running a SpringBoot App on Kubernetes 1.24, which i'm also using to learn several techniques with mostly using WebClient and with my newest attempt, also sending E-Mails with JavaMailSender etc.

Lately i was updating a few parts in my code, where i'm not sure anymore what was leading to the issue in the subject.

But i suspect it could have something to do with adding a new @Component for my EmailSender class or that i had to use @ComponentScan to access the mail package, as it was outside of my controller class package.

As e.g.:

```java
[...]
@Configuration
public class EmailConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
           [...]
        }
}
```

and also:

```java
@Component
public class EmailSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender emailSender;
    @Bean
    public void sendSimpleMessage(String to, String subject, String text) {
       [...]
    }
}
```

Also i've updated from Eclipse Temurin 17.0.6+10 to 17.0.7+7

To get more details, i've added the following to the application.properties:

```
management.server.port=8081
management.server.address=0.0.0.0
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,metrics,prometheus
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
```

So i've got the following response calling http://localhost:8081/actuator/health:

```json
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "H2",
        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 1022565265408,
        "free": 861403496448,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "path": "C:\\Users\\nick\\eclipse-workspace\\demoapp\\.",
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "DOWN"
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
    }
  },
  "groups": [
    "liveness",
    "readiness"
  ]
}
```

My pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.demo.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Demo SpringBoot</name>
    <description>Demo Spring Boot Example</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.20.0</log4j2.version>
        <netty.version>4.1.92.Final</netty.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.0</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was reading on the following at the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-availability.readiness):

> Tasks expected to run during startup should be executed by CommandLineRunner and ApplicationRunner components instead of using Spring component lifecycle callbacks such as @PostConstruct.

But i did not modified any behavior on such, so i'm currently not sure where and what to look for.

As i'm running on kubernetes, i'm using both endpoints to monitor my application, but now it keeps restarting as a both healthchecks fail with 503.

I'm hoping that it is just something simple i've forgot/changed and anyone knows or had that issue already.

Let me know if anyhow more information is required.

Thanks!

**Update:**

This only happens with Spring Boot 3.0.6, with 3.0.5 everything running fine with:

```json
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 1022565265408,
        "free": 863173750784,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "path": "C:\\<censored>\\.",
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "mail": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "location": "<censored>.net:25"
      }
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  },
  "groups": [
    "liveness",
    "readiness"
  ]
}
```

This [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35161) on GitHub might be related.

Comment: Why the email configuration as Spring Boot will add auto configuration for it. Also you shouldn't need the compont-scan as your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class should be in a top level package.

Comment: @M. Deinum i had to do this because my SpringBootApplication annotated class is outside of the package and couldn't be found otherwise. 

E.g.:

(SpringBootApplication)
my.demo.springboot.application.StartUpApplication.java
(My E-Mail package)
my.demo.springboot.bo.email.EmailConfiguration.java
my.demo.springboot.bo.email.EmailSender.java

Comment: That really shouldn't matter in this case, but as stated you don't really need the `EmailConfiguration`. In fact it actually influence auto configuration for the mail stuff (even the actuator part). So I suggest ditch that and instead specify the `spring.mail` properties instead, Spring Boot will now create and manage the mailsender for  you (and include a check as well for actuator).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks! To be honest i was actually confused because of this, as i saw it on several "googles" :-)

Because i was configuring it twice, in my application.properties the way you just mentioned, and inside that EmailConfiguration class. Now i've commented out my configuration class to only use the properties and i can see a new field mail with the status UP at the actuatur path. But so far it still returns me the 503 with livenessState DOWN and readinessState OUT_OF_SERVICE.

Comment: At least some progress. One thing I notice is the uppercase `S` in your property names, those don't really match the ones in the documentation try with a lowercase `s` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum originally i've found that on here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-liveness-readiness-probes#actuator-probes but changing it also did not had any effect. It's confusing why it is marked as down even if my app is running perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you execute some long running tasks with a `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner`? You can enable DEBUG or TRACE logging (which will flood your console) to see what is going on. One thing that might influence things is that you have both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` as a dependency and it doesn't know which to use. Have you explicitly configured which runtime (servlet or reactive) to use?

Comment: @M.Deinum no, i'm not using any Runners that are e.g. scheduled. But i'm explicitly using parts of jakarta.servlet.* (which is in web) and also webflux (needed for webclient)

I do have activated TRACE logging as such:

logging.level.root=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=TRACE
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=TRACE

and now it is actually getting flooded, but so far i couldn't find anything that leads me to a hint. I mostly see messages coming from: org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint

Is there something special i have to look for?

Comment: But have you instructed Spring to use SERVLET explicitly instead of Reactive? As you have both you have to explicitly specify which to use. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377675/dont-spring-boot-starter-web-and-spring-boot-starter-webflux-work-together on how to do that. Or add `spring.main.web-application-type` and set it to `SERVLET`.

Comment: A sorry, no i never did that as it was working fine without. But now, also by adding it as property e.g. spring.main.web-application-type=servlet/reactive or in my main method is still returning the same error.

Comment: Then I yield, with the little information you provided this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for support anyway! I still suppose it has to be a tiny thing somewhere :-)

Comment: Probably but with the config shown here that would be impossible to answer. Generally when discovered it is one of those facepalm moments (which I had plenty of in my 25 year career :) ).

Comment: @M.Deinum fyi: I was cleaning and clearing my whole code and at some step i figured out that: When i'm changing the version to Spring Boot 3.0.5, both livenessState and readinessState is UP and everything is running perfectly fine. Changing to version to 3.0.6 you see the above result where everything is down.

That means the error/issue must be somewhere in the newest version or there was something new/different implemented i didn't see so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related with GitHub issue [35161](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/35161). With a fix and its description as:

> Liveness and readiness probes return down when lazy initialization is enabled

Updating to Spring Boot Version 3.1.0 solved it for me (also [3.0.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.0.7) should have the fix, but untested from my side) and the health endpoint is up again (3.1.0 just has been published 3 days ago).

Details:

> This is a regression caused by the changes for [#34347](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/34347). The return type of the @Bean method has changed from ApplicationAvailabilityBean to ApplicationAvailability. This means that type information is lost and the bean factory cannot tell that it's an ApplicationListener.

```json
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "db": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "database": "H2",
        "validationQuery": "isValid()"
      }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        "total": 1022565265408,
        "free": 862148792320,
        "threshold": 10485760,
        "path": "C:\\<censored>\\eclipse-workspace\\demo\\.",
        "exists": true
      }
    },
    "livenessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "ping": {
      "status": "UP"
    },
    "readinessState": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  },
  "groups": [
    "liveness",
    "readiness"
  ]
}
```