# Reactive Spring Boot Application does not respect WebApplicationType

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot web app which should run as a reactive application using the default reactive client, Netty, however I am required to include several Maven dependencies which place `sprint-boot-starter-web` on the classpath. I understand this causes Spring to default to a servlet-style application using Tomcat instead of Netty, but according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.reactive) and [other StackOverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377675/dont-spring-boot-starter-web-and-spring-boot-starter-webflux-work-together?noredirect=1&lq=1), I should be able to circumvent this behavior by doing any/all of the following:

- annotate main class with @EnableWebFlux
- set spring.main.web-application-type to "REACTIVE" in properties
- use SpringApplicationBuilder to explicitly set WebApplicationType during app initialization

However, none of these options are working. I have tried setting the application type in every way imaginable, and still the application starts with Tomcat unless I explicitly exclude spring-starter-web from every dependency which includes it, which makes my pom.xml a mess.

In resources/application.yml:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: REACTIVE
```

...doesn't work.

In Application.java:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE);
        app.run();
```

...also doesn't work.

How can I force my application to run as a reactive WebFlux app with the default Netty client without tediously excluding all `spring-starter-web` dependencies? Running Spring Boot 3.2.2 on Java 17.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Spring Boot version 2.0, the "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency includes both Servlet and Reactive stacks. If you want to ensure that your application runs exclusively with the Reactive stack using Netty, you can exclude the servlet-related dependencies. You can use the following couple of dependencies and the main method as a solution for the question.

pom.xml;

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Exclude the servlet-related dependencies from spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <!-- Exclude any other servlet-related dependencies if needed -->
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Use spring-boot-starter-webflux with Netty as the reactive server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Main Method ;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux;

@EnableWebFlux
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```