# How to disable web environment in Spring Boot 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot

The answer to [about spring boot how to disable web environment correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187519/about-spring-boot-how-to-disable-web-environment-correctly/37225120) no longer works, as the method `.setWebEnvironment()` is gone.

What is the current, 2.0 way to disable web support completely?

For instance, my web application also contains a utility class that's used doing deployments, and needs to execute `main()` without firing up the web app.

More specifically about the behaviour I want to avoid, I see this in the log:

```
2019-09-25 11:48:12.151  INFO 19832 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-09-25 11:48:12.323  INFO 19832 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

and also the utility class doesn't terminate, and also takes up port 8080 while it's running.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825789/1840146

Comment: The 2nd (not chosen) answer in the other question applies to 2.0