# Simple web CRUD WebFlux application: how can Netty be useful?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jetty, netty, spring-webflux

I learned from here: [What's the difference between Jetty and Netty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385407/whats-the-difference-between-jetty-and-netty)
Netty is not a server at all.
but from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297055/10894456 I see it's the server.

Anyway I guess to run a web application there should be a server. So does Netty help to solve it? Or anyway need some kind of server ( Tomcat or Jetty or whatever)?
But from here: [Don't spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51377675/10894456) I learned Netty is not compatible with Tomcat...

Clarify please, what is the easiest way to create a reactive WebFlux crud application? How can Netty helps? What would be the server in case of using Netty? How Netty is compatible with it?

**Edit:**
Ok, I see Netty is not a server by itself, need to write something like:

```
public class NettyServer {

    private int port;

    // constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
        int port = args.length > 0
          ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
          : 8080;
 
        new NettyServer(port).run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
              .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
              .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) 
                  throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new RequestDecoder(), 
                      new ResponseDataEncoder(), 
                      new ProcessingHandler());
                }
            }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
              .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

But I also believe literally noone do this when creating a simple WebFlux CRUD service. So still the issue: How can Netty helps? What would be the server in case of using Netty? How Netty is compatible with it?

**Edit 2:** after hours of browsing I realized: `Netty` - is not a server, it's just a framework using cahnnels/NIO2, but `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` offers non-blocking and backpressure-ready TCP/HTTP/UDP clients & servers based on Netty framework.
But can use `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`, `spring-boot-starter-jetty`, or `spring-boot-starter-undertow` instead in this manner:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude the Netty dependency -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Use Jetty instead -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So just 2 concepts are confusing and mess each other: `Netty` and `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty`

Comment: Use this starter example https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/ and then go to a crud example https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/reactive-crud-apis-with-spring-webflux-88509634daa

Comment: Netty is a network library and Jetty is a http server, both are used for spring-webflux.

Comment: @Felipe so how web application works on Netty then accept requests and give responses? Who manages it?